# How do I read multiple parameters from a JSON request body in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Essentially, I have an API endpoint like this:

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult<UserDTO>> SignUp(string username, string password, Guid inviteId)
```

I want all these parameters to come from a JSON object in the request body like so:

```
{
    'username': 'foo',
    'password': 'bar',
    'inviteId': '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
}
```

I know I can create a class with these parameters as fields, but is there a cleaner way to do this? Also, how do I accept a parameter from the JSON object ***and*** another source? (i.e. `inviteId` could come from the JSON object or the query string)

**EDIT**: To clarify, I don't want to use a custom class, *or* something like JObject. I want the function to receive its parameters directly, without having to do any manual unpacking or parsing. Basically, the function signature should stay as `SignUp(string username, string password, Guid inviteId)`, and the solution should add on to ASP.NET's model binding functionality. Also, I don't want to use any third-party packages if I can help it.

Comment: I like to use the Json.NET library and the `dynamic` keyword.  Something like this might work.  `dynamic data = JObject.Parse(stringContent);` which would give you access to at runtime to `data.inviteId`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a few alternatives. I would use model-binding to accomplish this:

```
[HttpGet] // Or any HTTP method
public IActionResult GetSomething([FromRoute] string username, [FromQuery] SomeQuery query)
```

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding)

Comment: Yes, that's what I have. But instead of receiving the parameters from the route, query string, or whatever, I want to receive the parameters **as a JSON object**.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JObject` in `NewtonSoft package`.

1. import

   ```
   using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
   ```
2. Change the method like,

   ```
   public async Task<ActionResult<UserDTO>> SignUp([FromBody] JObject dataObject)
   ```
3. you can access the data by key,

   ```
   var username = dataObject["username"].ToString();
   var password= dataObject["password"].ToString();
   ```

Using this mechanism, you can process complex JSON objects without model binding.

Comment: I don't want to do any unpacking (`dataObject["username"]`) or parsing (`.ToString()`) manually inside the function. That should all be handled by some sort of middleware, like an input formatter. Also, I don't want to use any third-party packages if I can help it.